# Кол-во ответов в дубликате

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, дизайн, дубликаты

[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/611733/176217) закрыт как дубликат. Соответствующий баннер выглядит так:

> [image: баннер]

Разделение "6 ответов" на две строки выглядит некрасиво. Было бы неплохо организовать неразрывность этой фразы при отображении в упомянутом блоке.

Comment: Ну так организуй, в чём проблема? Alt+0160, если ты в винде.

Comment: @Qwertiy проверить можно, но: 1. Может кто-то против; 2. Однозначно не ясно какая это строка в transifex и не склеивается ли она через явный пробел движком; 3. Реализовать имеет смысл глобально, а не только для русской версии.

Comment: Я за то, чтобы сначала для русского сделать. Всё равно потом перевод слетит, если английский поменяют.

Comment: @Qwertiy значит надо постараться найти эту строку, я пока вижу как минимум 3 варианта подобных строк. Неоднозначность, короче говоря.

Comment: Не думаю, что в каких-то из них повредит неразрывный пробел, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю. Кажется я нашёл ту [единственную](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265894?key=caecc1a440e01e57f75e723115830044).

Comment: @Qwertiy поменял. Но строку в сыром виде не видно. Посмотрим как будет отображаться после подгрузки строк.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После использования неразрывного пробела (Alt+0160) по [совету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4480/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5#comment15420_4480) Qwertiy, в [переводах](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265894?key=caecc1a440e01e57f75e723115830044) фраза стала полностью отображаться на отдельной строке:

> [image: без переноса]

Можно считать, что всего лишь благодаря переводу ruSO в чём-то стал лучше enSO :)