# Нужен неразрывный пробел после числа минут

Tags: дефект, дизайн, комментарии, даты

Не нравится мне тут перенос строки после единицы:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: В англоязычной версии такого нет?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вроде есть, неразрывных пробелов я там тоже не обнаружил. Но, думаю, это тоже дефект)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а что мешает в переводе поставить неразрывный пробел?

Comment: @andreymal тогда это не проблемы локализации. Метка неуместна.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4480/176217

Comment: @αλεχολυτ но это можно решить через локализацию

Comment: @andreymal решить проблему можно разными способами. На Мете, кмк, не особо уместен подход, что если ТС указал метку, решать задачу нужно именно средствами, связанными с этой меткой (как на основном сайте это задаётся, например, метками ЯП). Если ТС хочет решить задачу через перевод это не делает саму задачу проблемой перевода.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я вообще подозреваю, что это *единственный* возможный вариант решения проблемы

Comment: @andreymal с точки зрений реалий - да. С точки зрения правильного решения в пределах SE - нет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и каким же должно быть правильное решение?